# Change Menu Bar size depending on the current div on screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu bar that changes it's size depending on the div that is currently displayed on the screen.

Something on the lines of this: http://housing.com/dsl

My current CSS for the menu and HTML Markups for the rest of the page are as follows:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#content1">1</a>
    <a href="#content2">2</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content1" id="content1">
    </div>
    <div class="content2" id="content2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color: #336699;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard. You would have to get the *width* of the div and then process it, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the div's width
    var divWidth = $("#content").width();
    // Update div's width
    $("#content").css("width", divWidth + 'px');
});
```

#### EDIT 1:

If you want you code to work dynamically as you change the browser's width, rather than on load, then you would have to bind it to `.resize()` event:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    // Get the div's width
    var divWidth = $("#content").width();
    // Update div's width
    $("#content").css("width", divWidth + 'px');
});
```

#### EDIT 2:

If you wish to do something as the page, let's say, scrolled down for `50px`, then you would want to use `.scroll()` function to achieve this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
            // Get the div's width
            var divWidth = $("#content").width();
            // Update div's width
            $("#content").css("width", divWidth + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

#### Online demo example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVXBJ/1/

Comment: I don't want to change the size of the div itself, but of the menu bar depending on the width of say `#content`. So will it follow the same steps as above? And can I use percentages instead of pixel values?

Comment: Yes, it should follow and just replace `px` with `%`. Try and let me know! I will elaborate in case it fails!

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant, if `content1` is displayed on screen, the size will change with the above code, yes?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically? As you change the size of the browser's window?

Comment: No no. That's already fixed. Have a look at the link I shared in the question. In that when I scroll to a particular div, the menu on the top changes size.